# signed kernel module not accepted

Tags: kernel, secure-boot

I signed a kernel module with MOK using:

```
$ sudo kmodsign sha512 \
  /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.priv \
  /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.der \
  ./ipu6-drivers/0.0.0/5.19.0-23-generic/x86_64/module/intel-ipu6.ko
```

And modinfo reports it as signed:

```
...
name:           intel_ipu6
vermagic:       5.19.0-23-generic SMP preempt mod_unload modversions 
sig_id:         PKCS#7
signer:         ubuntu Secure Boot Module Signature key
sig_key:        63:07:BC:9E:44:51:90:19:4E:DF:D6:E3:22:C9:6A:04:A0:BC:D3:C6
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
signature:      3B:29:E9:60:C5:DB:F8:A1:03:5A:2B:54:D1:8A:90:19:BB:0A:0A:46:
...
```

But when I attempt to load the module using modprobe, I get:

```
Loading of unsigned module is rejected
```

in my kernel log.

Why do the kernel and the modinfo differ in opinion on the module being signed?

The key also shows up in `mokutil --list-enrolled` output.

Comment: I am trying to do the same thing in Ubuntu 22.10, but the mok folder is empty. has this changed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because my kernel module was at two different locations:

```
/var/lib/dkms/ipu6-drivers/0.0.0/5.19.0-23-generic/x86_64/module/intel-ipu6.ko
/lib/modules/5.19.0-23-generic/updates/dkms/intel-ipu6.ko
```

...and I only signed one of them, which was not the one found by modprobe.